# Not able to select and click dropdown search query result with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to perform select and click action from the search box result dropdown for testing purpose. Though i dont get ant error but i'm stuck and not able to do so, search results came then disappeared immediately. Please any one help me out. Im using Python script to automate webdriver. Here is the screenshot below for reference.
[image]. I have tried webdriverwait for same action but it gives Timeout exception error. If there is any child actions from CSS to perform let me know. Here is what i tried

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
search.send_keys("flowers")

dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='flowers']")))
```

Apart from this snippet, i want to rather just perform enter key operation, where i get query result for 'flower' on this ecomm. website.

Here is the website URL- https://paytmmall.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you type `flower` in the `input field`, there are multiple **options** appearing based on the input provided. They are in `li tags` and under `b tag`.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://paytmmall.com/")
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput")))
search.send_keys("flowers")
time.sleep(3)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//li)[4]/descendant::b[contains(text(),'flowers')]"))).click()
```

`time.sleep` is just for visibility purpose. you can remove that as well.

Also this **xpath** `(//li)[4]/descendant::b[contains(text(),'flowers')]` is based on **xpath indexing** , since I think you wanna select the 4th option which is flower itself. In case you wanna `select` a different **option**, you would have to write the different `xpath`.

In case you are looking to just select the searched item, it's better to pass enter key once you type flower in the input field.

You can use the below code for that :

```
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput")))
search.send_keys("flowers")
time.sleep(3)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
   search = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
   search.send_keys("flowers")
   time.sleep(3)
   search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput")))                    
at first, it doesn't works but once i put wait in the first line of code it works well              im sorry for being a late responder so pardon, you can now close this ticket now

Answer (score 0):

The suggested options are not containing the text directly in `li` elements, they are inside child elements inside `li` elements.
Try this instead:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
search.send_keys("flowers")

dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li//*[text()='flowers']")))
```

Comment: I beg my part for late reply, i tried this but didn't works., thanks, now this issue has been resolved